# SQL Query Join plus sum and months sorting

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sorting, sum

i have a problem using the sum function with the inner join in the below query

```
SELECT distinct Datename(Month,(date)), year(date), SUM(tblpayment.Amount)  
FROM TblSubsc INNER JOIN TBLPayment ON 
TblSubsc.[Subsc ID]=TBLPayment.[Subsc ID] 
group by year(date),Datename(Month,(date))
```

it is giving the sum but the months are not sorted so i get

```
April
August
February
January
March
May
```

please any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add the order by clause

```
order by year(date) asc, month(date) asc
```

and add

```
month(date)
```

to group by too.

EDIT: remove "distinct" as it's not necessary in this case because the data is already grouped by month & date.

Comment: The datename function requires 2 arguments

Comment: i put what u said it gave me Msg 8127, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
Column "TblSubsc.Date" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: Add month(date) in group by also. I removed the second message for the datename function, I didn't read it correctly.

Comment: i did that too and giving me same error Msg 145, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.

Comment: select distinct is not necessary in this case because you already have a group by year, month.